# Лишние 2 пустые строки во всем проекте Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

Подскажите пожалуйста, во всем проекте появились дополнительные 2 пустые строки, как бы их удалить не в каждом отдельном файле, а во всем проекте сразу? Спасибо.

```
if (! defined('DIAFAN'))
{


$path = __FILE__; $i = 0;


while(! file_exists($path.'/includes/404.php'))


{


    if($i == 10) exit; $i++;


        $path = dirname($path);


    }


    include $path.'/includes/404.php';


}
```

Comment: форматирование в netBeans Alt-Shift-F, как я помню оно строки не удаляет

Comment: Я так понимаю, это `\r\n`?

Comment: @vp_arth точно, можно же по регулярке (y)

Answer (score 1):

#### Удаление всех дублирующихся переносов

*Включая те, что вы ставили намеренно*

- Выбираете папку в дереве каталогов
- <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>
- Галка <kbd>Regular Expressions</kbd> - установить
- <kbd>Search for</kbd>: `[\r\n]+`
- <kbd>Replace with</kbd>: `\n`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

#### Автоформатирование стиля

<kbd>Alt+Shift+F</kbd> или <kbd>Source</kbd>-<kbd>Format</kbd>

Настроить стиль кода(для каждого типа файлов) можно в <kbd>Tools</kbd>-<kbd>Options</kbd>-<kbd>Formatting</kbd>